# Adding and Subtracting values in Verilog

Tags: variable-assignment, verilog

I am writing a program that acts as a cash deposit box. 
Everything occurs on the clock edge.
If enable is true and reset is true, the value in the box resets to 0.
If enable is true and add is 1, we add the amount to the box.
If enable is true and add is 0 we subtract from the box.

Here is my code and test bench

```
module cashbox(output [15:0] value, input [15:0] amount, input add,enable, clock, reset);
reg value;

 always @(posedge clock)
 begin
if(enable) begin
  if(reset)begin
    value <= 0;
    end
  else begin
    if(add)begin
     value <= value + amount;
     end
    else begin
      value <= value - amount;
      end
    end

end    

end
endmodule

// cashbox testbench

module cashbox_tb;
reg [15:0] amt;
reg add, en, clk, rst;
wire [15:0] value;

cashbox cb(value, amt, add, en, clk, rst);

always
    #50 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    $display("Amount in box %d", value);
    clk = 1; en = 1; add = 1;
    rst = 1; #10 rst = 0;
     amt = 100; add = 1;
    #170 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 90
    #20 amt = 50; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 290
    #20 amt = 75; add = 1;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 490
    #20 amt = 35; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 690
    #20 amt = 50; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;
    #810 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Everything compiles but when I run it, it displays Amount in box X. It doesnt display a value

I changed my test bench to this
     // cashbox testbench

```
module cashbox_tb;
reg [15:0] amt;
reg add, en, clk, rst;
wire [15:0] value;

cashbox cb(value, amt, add, en, clk, rst);

always
    #50 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
   $monitor("Amount in box %d",value);
    clk = 0; en = 0; add = 0;
    rst = 1; #10 rst = 0;
    #10 amt = 100; add = 1;
    #170 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 90
    #20 amt = 50; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 290
    #20 amt = 75; add = 1;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 490
    #20 amt = 35; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;  // 690
    #20 amt = 50; add = 0;
    #180 en = 1; #100 en = 0;
    #810 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

And now my output is back to saying Amount in box X

Comment: I'm using an online compiler on tutorialspoint.com

Answer (score 2):

`$display` is only executed at time 0.  Change that to `$monitor` so that you get a display message every time `value` changes:

```
$monitor("Amount in box %d", value);
```

Here is the output I get with VCS:

```
Amount in box     0
Amount in box     1
Amount in box     0
```

Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section "21.2.3 Continuous monitoring".

I get compile warnings with VCS, and I get a compile error with Incisive.

This can be cleaned up by changing:

```
module cashbox(output [15:0] value, input [15:0] amount, input add,enable, clock, reset);
reg value;
```

to:

```
module cashbox(output reg [15:0] value, input [15:0] amount, input add,enable, clock, reset);
```

After that change, here is my output:

```
Amount in box     0
Amount in box   100
Amount in box   200
Amount in box   150
Amount in box   225
Amount in box   190
Amount in box   140
```